# When i run my project on xcode it shows

Tags: ios7

Xcode cannot launch apps on the simulated device “iPhone 6”, as it is currently running an app on “iPhone 4s”. Only one simulated device may be used at a time

Comment: I think the answer is actually in your question. You have a separate iPhone 4 simulator running with an app

Comment: Maybe. But often this happens when the simulator isn't even running, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

This means one of two things:

1. You have another project window open, and that project is debugging an app using the iPhone 4s simulator;
2. XCode has gotten confused and thinks you are still debugging something in the simulator, even though you are not. This happens to me pretty often, and I think it's a bug in XCode, in the way it interacts with the simulator.

For #1, go to the other project window(s) and click Stop button to stop debugging.
For #2, quit XCode and start it up again.